# Ruby's Thread#exit not exiting the current thread in Travis

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

I'm working on a school project in Node.js, for which we (my teammate and myself) added a bunch of integration tests ran by a Ruby script. As mentionned in the title, we use Travis to run this test at each push.

We work on a decentralised application, requiring us to start 3 servers for our tests to run. To do so, we start each server in a thread, and once all servers have started, we run the tests (using Postman's `newman` CLI) in one of the three threads (the one for which the server was the longest to start).

Exiting the script after the tests ran means stopping the servers and exiting their threads. To do so, I'm killing every server's process and exiting all of their threads, ending with the thread running the tests.

Unfortunately, this same thread always fails to exit, causing the Travis build to timeout and get into the `errored` state. Which is weird, as it all works nicely on my laptop.

The Ruby script's available on GitHub here: https://github.com/JosephCaillet/vinimay/blob/friends/run_tests.rb

Why is Travis failing to exit my thread and how can I fix it?

**Update**

To clarify some unclear parts of the initial post, here's the lifetime of the threads in the Ruby script:

1. Three threads are created. In each of them, a server is started on a different port.
2. When calling `thr.join` on each thread, the script watches the output of each server, waiting for a string containing "Server running at" to be outputed in stdout (so it knows when the server is actually running). Each time this string is found, a counter gets incremented.
3. When the counter get to three (meaning all of the servers have started), it then run the tests. This means the tests are ran in the thread for which the server was the longest to start.
4. Still in this thread, after the tests have been ran, the script kills each server process. It also call `exit` on their threads, except for the thread which was running the tests and is now exiting threads (as we can't have this thread exiting before the others, otherwise it'd let them in a permanent running state and the script would never end).
5. The script calls `exit` on the last thread and ends.

It's the 5th step Travis seems to have trouble with.

Comment: You said the same thread fails to exit, which thread is that? Are there any logs you can share from Travis?

Comment: No log in the Travis console except for the ones I already `puts` in the Ruby script.
I was talking about the thread running the tests. I'll update my post to make it clearer about the thread's lifetime.